# few $timeout issues - start on click, inserting function in it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout

I'v got something like this:

```
angular.module('TaskCtrl', [])
    .controller('TaskController',
        ["Service", "$timeout", function (Service, $timeout) {

                this.starter = function () {
                    Service.doSomething();
                    Service.doSomethingElse();

                };
            }])
})
```

I'm trying to make a delay between clicking on <kbd>Next</kbd> button and proceeding to the next view.

1. how to add `$timeout` here and force it to run on `ng-click` not right after page is loaded?
2. how to put `this.starter()` in `$timeout` function? I tried some options but I guess I suck at `this.<xxx>` dependencies.

Putting $timeout in Service itself is quite compiicated, because `this.starter()` uses things from three different services.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="button-bar">
<a class="button next-finish-button" ng-href="#/nextpage"
   ng-click="TaskCtrl.starter()">Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: could share your markup and show where the starter function is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
            this.starter = function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    Service.doSomething();
                    Service.doSomethingElse();
                    }, 100);
            };
```

Comment: undefined, it can't recognize any of "Service.xxx" dependencies.

Comment: Please share your Service code. If defined in another angular module, you will have to add it to the dependency of your TaskCtrl module

Comment: ok, I got it - your solution works pretty good, i've probably made some typos or something earlier. thanks very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('TaskCtrl', [ServiceModule])
    .controller('TaskController',['$scope','Service','$timeout', function($scope,Service, $timeout) {
            $scope.starter = function () {
                $timeout(function(){
                    Service.doSomething();
                    Service.doSomethingElse();
                },1000); // 1 second delay
            }; // end starter
     }]); // end TaskController & module TaskCtrl
```

**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="TaskCtrl">
    <!-- head stuff here -->
    <body>
       <div class="button-bar" ng-controller="TaskController">
          <a class="button next-finish-button" ng-href="#/nextpage" ng-click="starter()">Next</a>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```